# How do you split up large controllers into multiple files in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, controller

I'm building an express application which up until now has used a singular controller file named `users`. This contains various user related functions such as signUp/signIn/getPersonalInfo, which are exported using `module.exports`, and required in the router.

The problem is this file is now getting rather large and I would ideally like a folder structure such as the following:

```
controllers/users/registration.js
controllers/users/personalInfo.js
```

How can I do this such that I can still just require a single file in my router:

```
var users = require('../controllers/users/?');
```

and still have access to all the functions within each controller.

Also if there is a more efficient way of doing so please let me know.

Comment: You would need a `controllers/users/index.js` file to manually re-export all the children functions. Or you can do it via webpack's require to automate the manual work if you are using webpack.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but in my project make use of multiple functions with only one reference to my 'bootcamps' controller.

```js
const {
  getBootcamps,
  getBootcamp,
  createBootcamp,
  updateBootcamp,
  deleteBootcamp,
  getBootcampsInRadius,
  bootcampPhotoUpload
} = require('../controllers/bootcamps');
```

Feel free to take a look at my project for inspiration:

https://github.com/KristoferMar/NodeJs-Guide/blob/master/routes/bootcamps.js

Comment: Thank you that's very useful. I'm still a little unsure on how best to structure my controller files though. Say for example I have two models `USER` and `EMAILS`, where a user can have many emails. Would it make more sense to put a `getUserEmails()` function in a users controller or an emails controller? If emails belong to users surely `user.getUserEmails()` makes more sense instead of `email.getUserEmail()`? Or is that not the case?

Comment: That is a very good question but i would personally put "getUserEmails()" inside the e-mails controller because the data you are trying to get is very "email related". I would then parse an "authenticated user" as a parameter in the email controller to get user e-mails for that specific user. If you take a look inside my 'reviews.js' router you can see how i handle something a little similar to this when i do a ".put" 


https://github.com/KristoferMar/NodeJs-Guide/blob/master/routes/reviews.js

Comment: Say for example then when the member has to sign up, this process involves creating a new member record as well as a new email record. Where does this controller function sit because it manipulates both models? Similar for `getAccountInfo()` as this will return a user record and associated emails.